# How to print log when directly executing Cypress command under browser developer tool (F12 mode)

Tags: javascript, cypress

For ease of determining the correct Cypress syntax, I would like to be able to print log in F12 console as below example. However, I am having trouble to print the value (wrapped under cy. command) to the console. I have tried 'console.log', 'alert' and 'cy.log', none of them work. Thanks in advance for any advices.

[image]

20200728 - adding some sample code per feedback. This sample code uses Mozilla's website to ease discussion:

```
  cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .mzp-c-menu-title').then( (element) => {       
    console.log('Hello from Console')
    cy.log('Hello from Cy')
    console.log('Hello from Console'+element.text())
    cy.log('Hello from Cy ' + element.text())        
  })
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know Cypress, but a good practice is check the [official documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/debugging.html#Using-debugger)

Comment: both `console.log` and `cy.log` should work, are you sure it's not working? Could you provide your sample code rather than a picture?

Comment: Are you sure `[aria-colindex="4"]` exists?